Show that $x\mapsto f(f(x))/x$ is convex, where $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2(1-x)} - r, r\geq0$.

Let $r\geq 0$ be a given parameter. Define the function $f:[0,1)\to \mathbb R$ by $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2(1-x)} - r$. Define $g:f^{-1}[0,1)\to \mathbb R$ by $g(x)=f(f(x))$. Show that the function $\displaystyle h(x)=\frac{g(x)}{x}$ is convex on $I=g^{-1}[0,1)$.

Observations:

I verified this numerically for various values of $r\geq 0$.

The function $f$ is increasing and convex on the interval $[0,1)$, so $g$ is increasing and convex on $I$.

For $r=0$,
$$
 h(x)= \frac{g(x)}{x} = \frac{f(f(x))}{x} = \frac{x^{3}}{4} 
\cdot \frac{1}{1-x}
\cdot \frac{1}{2-2x-x^{2}}
$$
is a product of three positive, increasing, and convex functions on $I$, so $g(x)/x$ is convex on I.

Denote $f(x; r)$ the function $f$ for the specific choice of $r$, and $g(x;r_1,r_2):= f(f(x;r_1);r_2)$ with the domain $f^{-1}([0,1); r_1)$. Then numeric observations suggest that $\frac{g(x; r_1,r_2)}{x}$ is convex for any $r_1\geq 0$ and $r_2\geq 0$ on the interval $I_{r_1,r_2}=g^{-1}\left([0,1); r_1,r_2\right)$. Given that we know that the claim that $g(x,r_1,r_2)$ is convex on $I_{r_1,r_2}$ holds for $r_1=r_2=0$, a potential method of proof would be to show that the claim is preserved as $r_1$ and $r_2$ increase.

The second order derivative of $h(x)$ is a mess even for $r=0$:
$$
h''(x) = \frac{x \left(- x^{5} + 12 x^{4} - 12 x^{3} + 14 x^{2} - 24 x + 12\right)}{2 \left(x^{9} + 3 x^{8} - 9 x^{7} - 17 x^{6} + 48 x^{5} + 6 x^{4} - 100 x^{3} + 108 x^{2} - 48 x + 8\right)}.
$$


For $r=0$:

For $r=\tfrac{1}{5}$ (in response to @RiverLi):


Have you tried to compute the derivate of the function $g$?

What is exactly $I$? The problem is that $f^{-1}(0)=-r\pm\sqrt{r^2+2 r}$ (two values) and the same with $f^{-1}(1)=-r - 1 \pm \sqrt{r^2 + 4r + 3}$

Write down your function after substituting the definition of $f$. Then compute the second derivative and try to prove it is nonnegative.

@vanderWolf Thanks for the comment! I edited the question to resolve this indeterminacy by restricting the domain of $f$ to nonnegative numbers.

@max_zorn I agree that analyzing the the second derivative of $g$ would be the standard approach. Substituting for the definition of $f$ fully is perhaps not the best way to go as the Observation 4 (that I just added to the question) suggests. Perhaps substituting for $f$ partially would help, but there are too many ways to do it and finding the right way seems cumbersome. I hope there is some solution taking the advantage of Observation 3, that $g$ is convex for $r=0$ and imply that it also has to be convex for $r>0$ from there.

@PavelKocourek How about $r = 1/5$?

@RiverLi I don't see a problem for $r=1/5$, I added the graph to the question. Note that the interval $I$ is quite narrow then.

@PavelKocourek For $r = 1/5$, what is the interval you get?

@RiverLi For $r=1/5$ the interval is $I \approx (0.665, 0.726)$ as the graph suggests.
As $r$ increases the interval is increasingly tight, e.g. for $r=1$ its already only $I\approx (0.810,0.817)$.

@PavelKocourek Your intervals are different from van der Wolf's?

@RiverLi You are absolutely right, and I apologize for the confusion. I corrected the definition of $I$ in the question. The convexity of $g$ only holds where $f(f(x))\geq 0$. The numerical results suggest that $g$ is convex on $(f^{-2}(0),f^{-1}(1))$, where $f^{-2}$ is defined as in the edited question, but it is harder to verify it numerically as $f(f(x))$ explodes when $x$ approaches $f^{-1}(1)$, and in fact I only the result for $x\in f^{-2}((0,1))$.
The graphs and the intervals from my previous response correspond to the corrected definition of $I$.

@PavelKocourek OK. It seems not easy to deal with $f^{-2}$.

I changed the formulation of the problem slightly and added Observation 4, suggesting in which way I hope to be able to lead the proof.
